# URLImage does not retain placeholder if Internet image was not found

Tags: codenameone

I am creating a URLImage with a placeholder. The placeholder is first displayed until the Image is downloaded from the internet. If the Internet image is not found, the placeholder image is removed and a blank / white space is displayed.

I would like to keep the placeholder image in case the URLImage is not found. 
Is there a URLImage option to accomplish this?

Comment: There was a bug in URL image download which we fixed last week. In case of an error it should no longer fail. Can you do an update client libs and see if the problem still occurs?

Comment: I deleted the .cn1 project per Diamond' suggestion, refreshed libs and ran the project again, on the first run the placeholder images are shown and displayed. On subsequent run I see the empty / white spaces. I am not sure if things are getting cached causing this issue.  I implemented an adapter now such that if the downloadedImage is null, I return the placeholder image similar to URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE. This one seems to work for now

Comment: Look in the cn1lib directory at the files that were downloaded. What do they physically contain? Is it an HTML error message or something like that? Open the network monitor in the first "clean" run and look at the output, what's returned from the URL request?

Comment: The images are hosted on S3. In the event the image is not found, it is returning a 403 (forbidden status)  and an XML with more info (  error code, message requestId and hostId)

Comment: So is that error message written to the file? Diamond made a pull request last night where he might have fixed additional variations of this bug that I missed in the original fix. It should be integrated this Friday

Comment: That is correct, the error message is sent as an XML doc along with an HTTP 403. It may be a little mis leading , instead of returning File not found (404) , I think per my current config  (which is the default), S3 returns 403. I will try again this weekend!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your project library by right clicking your project and select properties on Netbeans. The latest Codename One lib fixed that issue and blank images should no longer be created.

You may have to clear your `.cn1` folder for this to work fine on Simulator and delete app on phone before re-installing to clear cache on actual devices.